# How are moving objects best represented/implemented in a pygame-based simulation?

Tags: python, loops, pygame, simulation

I am currently attempting to make a Bee Simulation for college and I have started working out the basics of how to do it.

The initial idea was to use PyGame and present the user with bees on the screen but for now I am just doing the basic functions first.

With the function which I am having issues with is the function where the bee will look for cells that are not being used and then go and use them. This is run on every new frame and run on every bee object so each bee will check each cell.

I'm using this code for this:

```
 for i in range (0,len(hiveCells)): 
             if hiveCells[i] == "": 
                print("Not taken") 
                hiveCells[i] = "B"

             else:
                 print("Taken")
```

But the issue with this is of course it finished within seconds and the bees had used the whole hive but I am needing a way to do this slowly and include time it takes to travel to that cell and then time it takes to actually use it?

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of using coordinates and it will move closer to those coordinates every loop and check if it has reached them.

Comment: you can use `time.sleep(t)` from `time` module to "slow down" the execution, not an efficient solution, of course.

Comment: Do you want to factor in the actual bee movements or do you just want to slow down execution speed (e.g., by introducing sleep time)?

Comment: The problem is more about factoring in the bee movment @moooeeeep so yeah not really wanting to go time.sleep route

Comment: It's hard to give an exact answer to your question without all the details. Also in your implementation one bee will occupy all cells if you're not using threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include travel time for each Bee you would first need to define some kind of distance measure. A trivial choice would be to use the euclidian distance.

In order to incorporate this into you model you would need the following additions

- Add a location (x,y), and possible (z) to each bee and each hive(cell)
- Define how much time (in seconds) elapses per frame update.
- Define the speed of the bee (in terms of m/s).
- Now per frame update you know how much time has elapsed since the last update, and you can (using the bee speed and location) compute the new location of the bee.
- The update frequency of the frame is now directly related to the time that is elapsed in your model.

Note that in order for this to work you would need some type of *ID* which relates the bee to the hive cell it claimed. I would recommend giving each bee a unique *ID*.

Then as soon as the bee claims a hive cell you store the unique bee ID in the hive cell, such that at each frame update you can compute the new location for each bee with respect to the hive cell it is flying to.

Additionally note that in order for this scheme to work the hive cell would need a location (which you could store in a similar sized array. But it might be the most clean to create an object for each Hive (cell), which stores it's coordinates and the bee-ID which claimed it. This would also allow you to further improve your model by adding additional information to (i.e. honey present, or whatever) the hive (cells)/bees.